# jQuery - Clone All Values Of All fields In A DIV To Other fields Inside Another DIV

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, indexing, each

Hello all respected programmers..

I have a little problem in cloning values from some fields (input, textarea, select) inside a div to other fields inside another div.

My actual problem here is I cannot copy checked checkbox correctly.

Here are my codes:

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
<button id="cloneto">Clone all values to second div</button>
<br><br>
    <span>FIRST</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="first[a]" class="a" value="a"/>
     <input type="text" name="first[h]" class="h" value="h"/>

    <select name="first[b]" class="b">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>       
    </select>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[c]" class="c" value="c" checked/>        
 <input type="checkbox" name="first[w]" class="w" value="w" />        
   <p>
<textarea name="first[d]" class="d">Textarea</textarea>   

</div>

<hr>
    <!--SECOND DIV-->
<div id="second">  
    <span>SECOND</span><br>    
    <input type="text" name="second[a]" class="a" value="second"/>
      <input type="text" name="second[h]" class="h" value="hsecond"/>


    <select name="second[b]" class="b">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>       
    </select>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="second[c]" class="c" value="checkbox"/>   
  <input type="checkbox" name="second[w]" class="w" value="ws" checked/>        
   <p>
<textarea name="second[d]" class="d">Different!</textarea>    
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#cloneto").on("click", function(){
    var values = [];
    $(this).parent().find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, v){
   values.push($(this).val());

   if($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox"){

if($(this).is(":checked")) {             $("#second").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, v){
             $(this).prop("checked", true);
   });          
       } else {   $("#second").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, v){
             $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });          
       }

   } else {
        $("#second").find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, v){
        $(this).val(values[i]);
        }); 
   }
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkdw6bc4/41/)

With these particular codes, I am able to check and uncheck the checkboxes inside the `second` div, but it can't do it correctly. When the last checkbox of the `first` div is not checked, then all of the checkboxes inside the `second` div won't be checked, and vice versa.

```
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {  
       $("#second").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, v){
         $(this).prop("checked", true);
       });          
  } else {
      $("#second").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, v){
           $(this).prop("checked", false);
      });          
  }
```

I don't know how to select the checkbox with the same index.

**Question:**

How to correctly check and uncheck the checkboxes inside the `second` div based on the `first` div?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Best Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so I come up with this solution which is perfectly working for me:

```
    $("#cloneto").on("click", function(){
        var values = [];
        var checked = [];

        $(this).parent().find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, v){
       values.push($(this).val());

       if($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox"){

   // read the checkbox and mark it out
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        checked.push("chk");
    }   else {
     checked.push("nchk");   
    }   


 $("#second").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, v){

// compare
if(checked[i] == "chk") {
                 $(this).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
           $(this).prop("checked", false); 
        }
        });          

       } else {
            $("#second").find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, v){
            $(this).val(values[i]);
            }); 
       }
        });

    });
```

What's happen?

1. create an array variable to store the checked and unchecked checkbox in the `first` div.
2. give it different value between checked checkbox and unchecked checkbox.
3. read the value inside `second` div checkbox iteration and do relevant stuff (checking and unchecking).

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7626svt/)